# get data from json in php

Tags: php, json

```
$json='{ 
        "status": true, 
        "data": { 
                "code": "44882S", 
                "quantity": 124740, 
                "amount": 124740, 
                "date": "2020-01-15"
                } 
    }';
```

and I've made the code and the code doesn't work

```
$get = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($get->data as $key) {
     $code = $key->code;
    $quantity = $key->quantity;
    $amount = $key->amount;
    $date = $key->date;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: just `dd($get)` and see if get the data.

Comment: `dd()` is from laravel and I'm not sure if he is using it. Use `print_r()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You requested json_decode to make the objects into arrays!

So either dont ask for the objects to be converted to an array

Also if you are looping over the object/array, you will get One entery per iteration and not all 4 at once.

```
$get = json_decode($json);
foreach ($get->data as $key=>$val) {
    echo "$key = $val";
}
```

OR treat each value as an array value

```
$get = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($get['data'] as $key=>$val) {
    echo "$key = $val";
}
```

Comment: We are looping over `data` already, so _inside_ the loop, there will not be a `$key->code`, but `$key`will be the value of `code` (and quantity, amount and date in the next three iterations) already.

Comment: @04FS Good point, I knew something was niggling in the back of my head

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, mate :-), but that edit still makes rather little sense. Now all four variables inside the loop get overwritten each time, so in the end they will all four of them contain `2020-01-15`. This doesn’t actually need a loop, OP’s attempt was a bit misleading to begin with.

Comment: That's true @04FS, otherwise this is just remapping.

Comment: @04FS Ha PENNY DROPPED, and code changed accordingly. Must be having a DUMB Half Hour :) Thanks for the sanity check :) :)